# why cannot we create spy for Parameterized Constructor using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I have only parameterized constructor in my code and i need to inject through it.

I want to spy parameterized constructor to inject mock object as dependency for my junit.

```
public RegDao(){
 //original object instantiation here
Notification ....
EntryService .....
}

public RegDao(Notification notification , EntryService entry) {
 // initialize here
}

we have something like below : 
RegDao dao = Mockito.spy(RegDao.class);
```

But do we have something that i can inject mocked object in the Constructor and spy it?.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can do that by instantiating your main class with parametrized constructor in your junit and then creating a spy from it.

Let's suppose your main class is `A`. Where `B` and `C` are its dependencies

```
public class A {

    private B b;

    private C c;

    public A(B b,C c)
    {
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
    }

    void method() {
        System.out.println("A's method called");
        b.method();
        c.method();
        System.out.println(method2());

    }

    protected int method2() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Then you can write junit for this using your parametrized class as below

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

    A a;

    @Mock
    B b;

    @Mock
    C c;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        a=new A(b, c);
        A spyA=Mockito.spy(a);

        doReturn(20).when(spyA).method2();

        spyA.method();
    }
}
```

Output of test class

```
A's method called
20
```

1. Here `B` and `C` are mocked object that you injected in your class `A` using parametrized constructor.
2. Then we created a `spy` of `A` called `spyA`.
3. We checked if `spy` is really working by modifying the return value of a protected method `method2` in class `A` which could not have been possible if `spyA` was not an actual `spy` of `A`.

Comment: i got `thenReturn() may be missing`

Comment: what if I only want to spy on that class, and I instantiate the argument as real object ?

Comment: @user2386301 that should still be doable in the constructor right?

Comment: Let's say we are creating an object for `B` inside a method dynamically instead of in constructor, Then there's no way of mocking `B`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be missing a dependency injection solution. Mockito is great for working with your DI to inject mocks. For example, you can use CDI, annotation your `Notification` and `EntryService` members with `@Inject`, declare `@Mock`s for both in your test, and then let Mockito inject those into your `RegDao` for testing.

Here's a working mockup of the test I think you're trying to run:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoSpyInjection {
    static class Notification { }
    static class EntryService { }
    static class RegDao {
        @Inject
        Notification foo;

        @Inject
        EntryService  bar;

        public RegDao() {
        }

        public RegDao(Notification foo, EntryService bar) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public Notification getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }

        public EntryService getBar() {
            return bar;
        }

    }


    @Mock
    Notification foo;

    @Mock
    EntryService bar;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    RegDao dao;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(foo, dao.getFoo());
        assertEquals(bar, dao.getBar());
    }
}
```